# Specifying morphTo method target id column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to specify target id column on morphTo method?

I'll give an example which is in documentation for laravel:

Post - Id, text

Video - Id, url

Comment - Id, text, commentable_id, commentable_type

But what if Ids on post and video were renamed to custom_id? How would I set up my eloquent model then? Thanks.

**Edit:**

I still don't get it here is the complete code:

Table structure:

```
comments - id, text, commentable_id, commentable_type, user_id
posts - custom_id, text
videos - custom_id, url
users - id, name, email, password,...
```

Comment model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Video model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Video extends Model
{

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable', 'commentable_type', 'commentable_id', 'custom_id');
    }
}
```

Post model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable', 'commentable_type', 'commentable_id', 'custom_id');
    }
}
```

User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

TestController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        $user = User::first();
        $comments = $user -> comments;

        foreach ($comments as $comment)
        {
            return $comment -> commentable;
        }
    }
}
```

And it still throws query exception Unknown column posts.id

Please explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the custom id field name in the relationship.

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable', 'commentable_type', 'commentable_id', 'custom_id');
}
```

There are the parameters

```
public function morphMany($related, $name, $type = null, $id = null, $localKey = null);
```

Edit : After going through the whole thing i've found out that using custom id only works from parent fetches the child relationship. But fails when trying to get the parent using the children. So fetching Post or Video from the comment would fail.

There's an active proposal on laravel internals to add the feature to allow specifying the custom id to make this work. https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/587

Comment: So I tried what you suggested but, when I for example do many to many relationship between user and comment(doesn't make much sense but for example). Set up the relations, but when I do something like: foreach (User::first() -> comments as $comment) { return $comment -> commentable }.... All I get is Unknown column posts.id...

Comment: @M.Novotny The example was for one to many relationship. You need to setup many to many relationship differently. Check it out here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations also you can get the custom id to it as well. `morphToMany($related, $name, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $inverse = false)`

Comment: But when I change custom_id back to id then it works without problem. So, the only reason why eloquent doesn't know what Id to look for is because I haven't set up many to many relationship? Honestly, I try to stay away from many to many polymorphic relationships, I prefer to create super table and handle polymorphism on database level. The whole structure then makes a much more sense to me than something-able here and something-able there. But it's weird that eloquent can make sense of the relationship with id perfectly fine but as soon as you change the column name to custom_id it breaks.

Comment: The 'something-able' is just a naming convention. In the end when you look at the table structure and see how laravel crafts the query, it's exactly what you would call simple and straightforward. The reason for the complication is to make it fluent with eloquent. But after using it in a couple of projects, you wouldn't find it complicated.

Comment: And where can I see how laravel crafts queries?

Comment: @M.Novotny you can add a listener to log all queries or use debug-bar https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar. I'd recommend using debug-bar in your dev setup, as it helps a lot in many aspects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144854/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-m-novotny).